# WFFM on Sitecore 7.0 version

Tags: sitecore

We are using WFFM on Sitecore 7.0 version and is going to upgrade to latest version Sitecore. In latest version, WFFM is moved to xDB. How do we upgrade the WFFM data to latest version of WFFM. Please suggest way.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should make use of the analytics conversion tool from Sitecore with the WFFM plugin (can be downloaded from [SDN](https://sdn.sitecore.net/Products/Sitecore%20V5/Sitecore%20CMS%207/Update/7_5_rev_141003.aspx) same goes for the plugin).

Since you are upgrading from v7 to latest, you will need to go through the sitecore v7.5. Once you complete the upgrade to v7.5, execute the conversion tool to import the data to xDB